# Style not applied

Tags: css, knockout.js, firebug

I see in Firebug that my style (`background-color`) is apparently on the element in html view, but not in element.style in the style tab. In the document I do not see the effect of the style, however if I manually add it in the style tab on a class that is present, it works. 
**How can this be?**

I have `!important` on the style on the element, and don't see anything that could override it

Edit, even with the value stated literally here, no dice:

```
   <div class="fl oh rounded" data-bind="attr:{style:'display:block, background-color:#ff0000 !important;'}">
```

However, this works.

```
<div class="fl oh rounded" style="background-color:#ff0000 !important;">
```

So, if I add the style inline and not in a knockout binding, it works... However, I can see that the binding is working as the bound color appears in the html in firebug (but not in element.style in the style tab, but the ko bound color is not seen)

Comment: code or link of site plz

Comment: Please show us your code, maybe you are overwriting it later, maybe something lies above it, it's hard to guess.

Comment: The question is, under what circumstances (I know of none) can a style appear inline on the element, but NOT in element.style in firebug???

Comment: @Tom It can't. My guess is you're wrong at some stage. Show us your code so we can verify

Comment: If you show your css and the part of the pagethat causes problems, it will be solved in minutes. People here are quite good with css magic!

Comment: I have edited the question to add some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why, but it was that out-of-place looking `display:block` that caused this oddity.